# How to save the state of a checkbox without extra variables?

Tags: java, android, state, checkbox

I have over 100 different checkboxes in 6 activites and i would like to save the state of each, so that when i switch from one activity to another, it remains checked. Do i really have to create over 100 booleans to save each checkbox separately or is there an easier way to save and read out the states? I thought of using a loop but i cant really think of an intelligent way to do this. Would be great if anyone could help! 
This is an example of one of my checkboxes: Its supposed to add a String to an ArrayList object when the box gets klicked and delete the String when the box gets unchecked. It works fine, but when i leave eg. Actvity1, go into Activity2 and come back to Acivity1 to uncheck one of my checkboxes, the string is added to my ArrayList a second time instead of beeing removed.

```
    myBox1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (myBox1.isChecked() == true)
                helperActivity.myStringArrayList.add("myString1");

            else {
        helperActivity.myStringArrayList.remove("myString1");}
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save the checked state for each of your checkboxes.

```
// Access the default SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences preferences = 
  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

...

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
// Save the checked state
editor.putBoolean("myBox1", true);
editor.commit();

...

// Get and set the checked state
boolean myBox1State = preferences.getBoolean("myBox1", false);
myBox1.setChecked(myBox1State);
```

The advantage of this scheme is that these settings will survive application restarts.

Comment: That works fine, but still, when i go backt to an activity where I checked a checkbox before, the green tick isnt there anymore. So I think the sytem gets it now, but how can i connect it to the views?

Comment: @C.Mandy Assuming you're saving the preferences correctly, when you display the activity, are you setting its checked state?  See my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

If the count of checkboxes is the same, keep a boolean array

Comment: Unfortunately not. If necesarry i will change them, but i was wondering if there isnt an easier way to can avoid it...

Answer (score 0):

You could map the id of the checkbox to it's state using a global HashMap. Then you subclass Checkbox, overriding as needed to save/restore the state into the Map, and use your class in the xml files instead. 
You could then save and restore the Map when the app starts, use this to write to a file:

```
        file = context.openFileOutput("checkbox_state.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(myCheckboxesState);
```

And this to read from one:

```
        file = context.openFileInput("checkbox_state.prefs");
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(file);
        myCheckboxesState = (Map<Integer, Boolean>) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

From the top of my head I think this is the best way.